# Is the order (in which insertion events in MongoDB event stream arrive) the same as the natural order of documents in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

According to the MongoDB documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-natural-order , there is a *natural order* in which the documents are actually stored on disk.

Also, if you subscribe to a Change Event Stream https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/change-events/ , you do not seem to have any possibility to specify the order of events you want. As they are flowing from the oplog, I suppose that you get them in the same order in which they are written to the oplog.

So, actually there are 2 questions:

1. Is it true that the events in the change event stream arrive in the 'oplog order'?
2. Is this 'change event order' same or different from the 'natural order', if we only consider insertion events (and the collection only receives inserts and does **NOT** receive any updates/replaces/etc)?

Answer (score 0):

> If it true that the events in the change event stream arrive in the 'oplog order'?

I don't see this stated in the documentation. Seems reasonable, if you want to confirm I would raise this through official MongoDB support channels.

> Is this 'change event order' same or different from the 'natural order'

Natural order applies to documents *stored* in a collection. Every insert can, for example, change the order of all other documents. So change stream events cannot be "in natural order" (this order doesn't apply at all to change stream events).